# length of train which has passed through tunnel

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A train is travelling at a speed of 96 km/hr. It takes 3 s to enter a tunnel and 30 s more to pass through it completely. What is the length of the train?

Comment: When observed from the tunnel or from the train?

Comment: @ABC:  the relativistic effects at $96$ km/hr are rather small.

Comment: This is all the data that I have.Answer given in the book is 80 metres.

Comment: Sure, but I think that showing that the question has other interesting sides to it, has a larger effect than patronizing the OP with the "what have you tried?" question.

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried to do. What are your thoughts on the problem? Questions will be closed if you don't make an effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Entering the tunnel means crossing own length

Crossing the tunnel mean travelling own length + that of the tunnel

Comment: but length of tunnel is also not given?plz elaborate

Comment: @ayush, the length of the train $=3 s\cdot 96$km/h. In fact, we can deduce the length of the tunnel. Please try

Comment: speed of train=(80/3)m/s and length of train=speed*3 sec=80m.Infact,we don't even need the information regarding 30s.Am I right?

Comment: @ayush, nice to hear that. Would mind trying to calculate the length of the tunnel?

Comment: The length of tunnel=speed of train*33 sec.Is that so?

Comment: @ayush, have you followed my last hint? It should be $(33-3)$sec$\cdot$speed of train

Comment: why 3 sec are subtracted?plz explain

Comment: @ayush, Last line of my hint : "Crossing the tunnel mean travelling own length + that of the tunnel"

Comment: OK ,so we have to start the time from the moment the train is completely inside the tunnel to calculate the tunnel length.That's the logic,right?

Comment: @ayush, yes, because in $30+3$ sec, the train crosses tunnel $\implies ?$

Answer (score -1):

96 Km/hr equivalent to (80/3) m/s.
It takes 3s for a train to enter into the tunnel.

Hence, length of the train = (80/3) *3

Therefore, 80m is the length.

The second part stating 30s is not really required for calculating the length.

Comment: The 30 seconds is useful I guess because it tells us that the tunnel is sufficiently long.